# Ingesting Huge CSV on Rails/Heroku: MySQL Connection Closed - SignalException: SIGTERM

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku

I've got a colossal CSV file (2.4 GB) hosted remotely (s3) which I'm trying to ingest into my rails app.

I've loaded it into temp and seems to work fine, but the connection keeps terminating on me `SIGTERM` about ten minutes after I begin to ingest / iterate over the file.

I'm on heroku running rails 4.2 with mysql 0.3.20.

What am I missing? How do I get this done?

```
rake aborted!
SignalException: SIGTERM
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `block in query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `handle_interrupt'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:299:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:460:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:299:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:235:in `exec_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:336:in `select'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:38:in `select_one'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:43:in `select_value'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:314:in `exists?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `exists?'
```

Comment: A remote diagnosis is difficult, but I would guess your running out of memory. You can try `heroku labs:enable log-runtime-metrics` to monitor it.

Comment: How are you parsing the csv file?  Are you using rails standard libraries to do it?  Also, are you throwing all of the data directly into a database or are you instantiating objects and cleaning up the input before data entry.

Comment: @slowjack2k thanks.

Comment: @bkunzi01 I'm using the CSV library. There's a considerable amount of work being performed on each row, including checking to see if a certain object exists, then creating two different objects, formatting fairly extensively and saving. Clearly this is the problem. How to refactor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it two ways: Use the SmarterCSV gem and test it locally first to make sure it can handle the size.  If the size isn't an issue this would be your best bet since it makes it very easy to process large csv's before input.  If that doesn't work you can do this:
Use mysql's import feature (discussed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html ) to first directly throw the data into a table in mysql.  Then, you can iterate through the records and transfer the data to the appropriate table using rails `find_each` method to avoid overloading the garbage collector.  I'm not sure if the import feature works the same as postgres' `COPY` but if it does make sure you create a table without a primary key in rails to hold the initial data transfer if your csv file doesn't have a primary key column.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to ingest locally and then try an SQL import. Been running it for 36 hours now, and it's slow af! Wish me luck

Comment: Import is built to handle massive data dumps so that will do it where CSV digests fail.